# Conditional statement in matlab function argument

Tags: matlab

I am wondering if its possible to have conditional statements in a function argument.
for ex, 
 testarray = [1,5,8,5,7,23,61,16]

psum = sum(testarray>2 & testarray<10)

will it possible to implement something like this in matlab.

I would really appreciate an example.

Comment: Do you want the psum to be equal to the sum of all integers in the array that are bigger than 2 and less than 10?

Comment: yes something like that..i want to see if we can implement something like this in a function argument..so calling a function if that conditional statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, please see the example below using your data.

```
testarray = [1,5,8,5,7,23,61,16]; % your array
```

Find sum of all numbers greater than 2 and less than 10 in testarray

```
psum = sum(testarray(testarray>2 & testarray<10));
```

The idea is that you find the indices of the numbers that meet the condition (i.e., testarray>2 & testarray<10 in this case), extract the numbers by indexing into testarray, and then sum them.